# Is there a problem of Kol Isha when Rina is singing in the tents of the righteous?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Psalms 118:15:

ק֤וֹל ׀ רִנָּ֬ה וִֽישׁוּעָ֗ה בְּאָהֳלֵ֥י צַדִּיקִ֑ים

The voices of Rina and Yeshu'ah are in the tents of the righteous

I can't see a problem with Yeshu'ah ( I know some boys named "Yeshu'ah" and, no, they're not Christian or J for J) singing. But if Rina sings in the tent where the *tzadikim* are, isn't there a problem of *Kol Isha*?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The men are in the _beis midrash_. Their wives are in their tents, listening to Rina & Yeshua'ah (a married couple).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, but you forget that BOTH Rina AND Yeshu'ah are singing at the same time!

Chazal say that "Ayn shomin shnay kolos ke'achas," which is why it's impossible to pay attention to your wife when you're watching TV. Since the sound is a mixture of both Rina and Yeshu'ah, it's permissible for them to be singing in the presence of the tzaddikim (Sh”t Sridei Esh 2:8).

But why only the tzaddikim? Since "Lo yamish Yeshu'ah mitoch ha'ohel," we know that he was already present when Rina started to sing. The tzaddikim are zrizim, so they are careful to command Yeshu'ah to sing along with Rina. By rov ha'am, we are afraid that they will be less mindfull and neglect to tell Yeshu'ah to sing, thereby leading to an aveirah of kol isha. That is why we restrict the singing to ohalei tzaddikim.

Comment: Really good. I wish I could vote more than once. I liked the part about the wife and TV. Though, in my case, my wife is like Rash"i when it comes to T.V. There's always something on T.V. that she comments on.